# Summation of sgn function

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I seen the equation $\sum_\sigma(\operatorname{sgn} \sigma)^2=k!$, where $\sigma\in S_k$ ($S_k$ is the symmetric group). How can I prove this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{sgn}\sigma \in \{1,-1\}$, then $(\text{sgn}\sigma)^2 = 1$ for all $\sigma \in S_k$. 
Hence:
$$
\sum_{\sigma}(\text{sgn}\sigma)^2 = \sum_{\sigma} 1 = k!
$$